# How to define "eventually a subset"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, hausdorff-measure

Let $(C_n)_n$ be a sequence of nonempty subsets of $[0,1]$ (we can assume that the $A_n$ are open/closed if it helps). Let $P$ be a nonempty subset if $[0,1]$.

> What is a natural way to formalize the claim "$C_n$ is eventually a subset of $P$", or, in other words, "In the limit, $C_n$ is a subset of $P$" without requiring that any $C_n$ be a subset of $P$?

If $(C_n)_n$ is decreasing, then it would be natural to simply require that $\cap_n C_n \subseteq P$. But I don't want to restrict myself to decreasing sequences.

Another idea I had was to use the Hausdorff metric to induce a topology on the space of nonempty subsets of $[0,1]$. Then we can at least talk about convergence of sequences of subsets in a rigorous way. But even after doing that, I'm not sure how to capture the idea I want. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not: **Definition.** The sequence $(C_n)$ is *eventually a subset* of $P$ if there exists $N$ such that $C_n\subseteq P$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: I don't agree with the fact that if $C_n$ is a decreasing sequence, then "$C_n$ is eventually a subset of $P$" should be equivalent to "$\bigcap_n C_n\subseteq P$", at least not according to common mathematical usage of the word "eventually". Given a sequence $a_n$, a property $\mathcal Q$ holds *eventually* if there is some $N$ such that $\mathcal Q(a_n)$ is true for all $n\ge N$, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Spenser Right, thanks. I will add this to the post, but I don't want to assume that any $C_n$ is necessarily a subset of $C$. Compare: The sequence $(1-1/n)$ is "eventually" $1$, but no member of this sequence equals $1$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Fair enough. I'm not really wedded to that example, but I thought it might help illustrate the point. Maybe I should have stuck to "in the limit" rather than "eventually".

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is rather open-ended I'll mention the following construction:

$$B = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty}\left( \bigcup_{i=n}^{\infty} C_i\right)$$

$B$ is the set of points that are in an infinite number of the $C_n$. Notice that it takes a possibly non-decreasing sequence of sets and converts it to a decreasing one by taking less and less of the "infinite tail". Your saying what you thought would be good for a decreasing sequence reminded me of it. And of course the "subset" part would translate to $B \subset P$.

Although the word I associate with this construction isn't "eventually" but "essential", as in "B is the essential part of $(C_n)_n$", because points that are in only a finite number of the of the $C_n$ get left out of $B$ -- you have to really be an essential member of the sequence to end up in $B$. I'm curious to know how this might correspond to your intuition.

Comment: Thanks. I'd considered this, and it is appealing. Though maybe $$\bigcup_{n}\bigcap_{i \geq n} C_i$$ corresponds more closely with what I want intuitively, which amounts to a definition that is weaker than what you suggested.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's "all the elements that, at some step, get in the sequence and then stay in the sequence, not stepping away even once", or "eventual lifers". Interesting. Though I would describe yours as stricter than mine, not weaker -- yours is a subset of mine, I'm pretty sure, so you reject some elements that I include.

Comment: Oh, I meant that if $C_n$ is eventually in $P$ in your sense, then it's eventually in $P$ in my sense. So your definition implies mine, but not vice versa.

Comment: Hmm, it's not a crucial point, but I think the inclusion goes the other way. If some point is in all of the $C_{2n}$ but not in any of the $C_{2n+1}$ then it will be in mine but not yours, no? Though I confess that unwrapping these definitions bends my brain a bit.

Comment: I agree with you about the subset inclusion. So if your limit is a subset of P then so is mine but not necessarily vice verse. So your definition of an eventual subset implies mine.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you were saying now.